# Find file in project (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Have visual studio 2012 feature of search only files from soulution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer where it says "*Search Solution Explorer (Ctrl+ü)*".
Here you can search for files from the solution.